# HTML sanitation with toastr and angular translate

Tags: angularjs, toast, angular-translate, html-sanitizing

I have a factory called ToasterFactory, which will serve the toasters in my application.

```
function toast(toastType, translateKey) {  
toaster.pop(toastType, $translate.instant(translateKey));
```

At the moment i need to send a toast with some html code, mainly *breakline*
I know that for the toaster i will need to set the **bodyOutputType** as 'trustedhtml'
Yet my toastr keeps getting the message with the *breakline* printed in it.
I assume its the $translate service that is sanitizing the html, since it works well if i send a string without any translate service included
How can i make the $translate unsanitize?